# Parted Magic memory test

Tags: memory, hardware-failure, livecd

I have a computer with possible memory (RAM) failure. How can I test this with a Parted Magic live CD? I see that it is advertised on the website

[`partedmagic.com`](http://partedmagic.com)

```
Test memory for bad sectors.
```

I booted from the disk but only see tests for hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Memtest86+**
It's found under `Extras in the boot menu` along with the character-based MHDD which will gather and display your hard drive's smart info.

[image]

[image]